# Is it possible to paint any country with any color in google maps by country name?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, region, regions

I want to paint any country with any color and cover it in google maps. I find a way to draw polygon by coordinates:

```
    var mypolygon;
    var polyCoords = [
      new google.maps.LatLng(40.96985437850034, 45.871337890625),
        new google.maps.LatLng(40.936664923030236, 49.00244140625),
        new google.maps.LatLng(39.76454453848205, 47.50830078125)
    ];
    mypolygon = new google.maps.Polygon({
        paths: polyCoords,
        strokeColor: "#FF0000",
        strokeOpacity: 1,
        strokeWeight: 2,
        fillColor: "#FF0000",
        fillOpacity: 1
    });
    mypolygon.setMap(map);
```

It works, but it is not possible (or its very difficult) to find all border coordinates of country. Asume that possible. It will be approximately, not exactly.

Is there any way to cover a country with any color by it's name? For example, for our country - **Azerbaijan**: "`az`".

Comment: Something like [this](http://www.geocodezip.com/geoxml3_test/v3_FusionTables_query_sidebarF_local.html?country=Azerbaijan)?

Comment: yess, just like that, if possible, to set opacity: 1, to cover full, region names not seem.

Comment: You can find country boundaries here:
http://www.naturalearthdata.com/downloads/

Comment: @geocodezip How can I get that functionality on my custom google map?

Comment: Look at the source code.